# Seg fault/error 216 when using Fillchar()

Tags: pascal, dynamic-memory-allocation

After I added `Fillchar()` looking for do C's `memset()` equivalent in pascal the program give a runtime error 216.

Here's my code (if I remove FillChar() it works fine):

```
function NewFoo(name : string) : ptrfoo;
var sym : ptrfoo;
begin
    new(sym);
    FillChar(sym, SizeOf(foo), #0);
    sym^.name := name;
    NewFoo := sym;
end;
```

`foo` is a `record` and `fooptr` a pointer to it defined as `type fooptr = ^foo;`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Fillchar` takes an *untyped parameter*, not a pointer. As it is you are overwriting the pointer itself (and memory well beyond it) with zeroes. You want to dereference the pointer to use it with `Fillchar`:

```
FillChar(sym^, SizeOf(foo), #0);
```

Untyped parameters are the parameters of the form `const foo`, `var foo`, `out foo` with seemingly no type attached to them. They cannot be assigned or used directly, but you can dereference them and get a pointer to them. Basically, they are syntactic sugar to be able to pass records and other variables around as if they were blobs of data without having to take a pointer to them C-style from the calling end (in reality it's a bit more complex, but that's the gist of it).

Comment: Thanks very much. How I've searched a lot on internet for example of how to do a dynamic allocation + fill it with zeros `malloc()/memset()` C world and so compare to my code but I can't find.

Comment: @TheMask This is the equivalent (more or less). The Pascal semantics are just not the same as the C ones, this is probably the most annoying difference if you're coming from a C background. It just takes some getting used to.